# The difference between Rows.Count and RowCount

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there a difference between `myDGV.Rows.Count` and `myDGV.RowCount`?

Also both of these seem to be returning Number of rows in the underlying table + 1 e.g they are returning 4 for a single field table such as the following. Are the headers added to the counts?:

```
myField
x
y
z
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**RowCount**: Gets or sets the number of rows displayed in the DataGridView.

**Rows.Count**:  Returns the number of rows

Comment: thanks - how about the second question - is the header row counted in Rows.Count ?

Comment: so why if the underlying table has 3 rows then the DGV rows.count is returning 4 ....does the empty row at the bottom of the DGV count as 1 ?